# Buddy devops build fail: java11

Tags: maven, build, continuous-deployment, java-11, maven-compiler-plugin

When I run my build with `mvn clean install` locally its all ok, I use java11.

but when my pipeline in Buddy wants to run it I get this error

```
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project web-testing: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]`
```

Is there a way or something I have to run before so its java is set to 11?

Edit:
found it in the environment select openjdk11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it in the environment tab of your maven execute select openjdk11 as image